# Why Array in Java always need to fixed size?

Tags: java, arrays

As the title, i want to know why array always needs to fixed-size, instead of arrayList doesn't. Thanks

Comment: Of couse, but why they don't use ArrayList for all situations?

Answer (score 4):

An `ArrayList` is backed by an array, whose size is fixed, but the `ArrayList` class contains code that creates a larger array and copies the existing array to it when the existing array is full.

That's the difference between arrays and `ArrayList`s.

Comment: many thanks. Btw, can you explain for me strong and weakness of each (Array, ArrayList)?

Answer (score 0):

There is big difference between array and lists:
1) if we certainly know size of collection - this is array, we need no dynamicaly changing size.
2) if we don't know, how many elements will be in our collection - this is list, where size is not fixed.

In this answer "collection" doesn't means Collection class in Java, it's just a a bunch of some objects

Comment: 1) if we certainly know size of collection - this is array .. Wrong. There we should use an array. Also: they can be used as soon as we know the maximum elements, not just the number of elements already in there.
Collection is an interface, not a class.

Answer (score 0):

1. The main difference between Array and ArrayList in Java is that Array is a fixed length data structure while ArrayList is a variable length. You can not change length of Array once create, but ArrayList can re-size itself.
2. Another difference between Array and ArrayList in Java, you can not store primitives in ArrayList, because it can only contain Objects. Array can contain both primitives and Objects.
3. The Array is not a class, while ArrayList is an object with many methods.
4. The elements of the Array retrieved with for loop. The elements of the ArrayList can be retrieved with for loop and iterators.
5. The Array cannot be synchronized, while ArrayList can be obtained a synchronized ver.

etc....